# VScode, NestJS, git submodule typeorm init is done in the submodule and not main directory

Tags: typescript, visual-studio-code, nestjs

I have a project like this

```
my_project
|
|
|
|
\----my_submodule
    |
    |
    |
    \----package.json
    \----tsconfig.json
|
|
|
\----package.json
\----tsconfig.json
```

my_project/package.json and my_project/my_submodule/package.json are the **same**

```
{
  "name": "my_project",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "main": "handler.js",
  "scripts": {
    "lint": "eslint . --ext .ts,.tsx",
    "migration:generate": "ts-node -r tsconfig-paths/register ./node_modules/.bin/typeorm migration:generate -p -d src/local-data-source.ts src/migration/migrations",
    "migration:up": "ts-node -r tsconfig-paths/register ./node_modules/.bin/typeorm migration:run -d src/local-data-source.ts",
    "migration:list": "ts-node -r tsconfig-paths/register ./node_modules/.bin/typeorm migration:show -d src/local-data-source.ts",
    "migration:down": "ts-node -r tsconfig-paths/register ./node_modules/.bin/typeorm migration:revert -d src/local-data-source.ts",
    "db:diagram": "ts-node -r tsconfig-paths/register ./node_modules/.bin/typeorm-uml src/ormconfig.json"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "pg": "^8.8.0",
    "reflect-metadata": "^0.1.13",
    "typeorm": "^0.3.9"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@types/node": "^16.11.10",
    "@typescript-eslint/eslint-plugin": "^3.6.0",
    "@typescript-eslint/parser": "^3.6.0",
    "eslint": "^7.4.0",
    "eslint-config-airbnb-base": "^14.2.0",
    "eslint-import-resolver-alias": "^1.1.2",
    "eslint-plugin-import": "^2.22.0",
    "eslint-plugin-jest": "^23.18.0",
    "eslint-plugin-module-resolver": "^0.17.0",
    "eslint-plugin-prettier": "^3.1.4",
    "ts-node": "10.7.0",
    "tsconfig-paths": "^4.1.0",
    "typescript": "4.5.2",
    "typescript-eslint": "^0.0.1-alpha.0"
  },
  "config": {
    "typeorm": {
      "migrations_path": "src/migration"
    },
    "commitizen": {
      "path": "./node_modules/cz-conventional-changelog"
    }
  }
}
```

when I run npm install the typeorm is installed under `my_project/my_submodule`

> how can I make sure its installed under `my_project`
> Also, for other team members that dont work with VSCode, the typeorm is installed correctly- under `my_project`, why?!

I tried adding `rootDir` to both directories and it didnt work

Answer (score 0):

I solved it by adding the submodule folder as another folder in vscode.
So, under vscode I have

my_project (this also contains "my_submodule")
my_submodule

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).